# Using libdl.so in MinGW

Tags: dll, mingw

I want to generate a dll file in MinGW, I have several object dependencies in order to do that, one of my object dependencies is libdl.so, I add this object in unix simply as :

```
g++ xx.o yy.o /usr/lib/libdl.so -o module.so
```

but in MinGW, I don't have any idea how to add this object. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [MinGW port of libdl](http://code.google.com/p/dlfcn-win32/) that you can use just like under Unix. Quote from the website:

> This library implements a wrapper for dlfcn, as specified in POSIX and SUS, around the dynamic link library functions found in the Windows API.
>
> It requires MinGW to build.
>
> You may get pre-built binaries (with MinGW gcc 3.4.5) and a bundled source code from the Downloads section.

The following commands build and install it in a standard MinGW installation (to be run from your MinGW shell):

`./configure --prefix=/ --libdir=/lib --incdir=/include && make && make install`

To compile your library as a DLL, use the following command:

`g++ -shared xx.o yy.o -ldl -o module.dll`

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem (msys2, 32bit version of compiler etc.).

For me I found out that the libdl.a was available in /usr/lib but not in /mingw32/lib. I was able to solve the problem by linking it to the /mingw32/lib folder:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/libdl.a /mingw32/lib
```

Comment: That's going to be the msys2 layer libdl, not a pure win32 libdl.