# SQLITE with C for an embedded application

Tags: c, sqlite, embedded, microcontroller

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.
I want to use SQLITE with C for an embedded system. I'm running into all sorts of problems trying to interface SQLITE with C.
I would like a step by step explanation on what all I need to do to get it running. Everything from the compiler I would need, editing path variables, to what all files I'd need to include in my project.
Please assume I'm starting from scratch.
Though there have been similar questions in this forum, I believe that comprehensive explanation would be useful to many.
**EDIT -**
I'm hoping a cortex m0 based microcontroller with the bare min required specifications should work. Though, currently, I can't even get sqlite to work with Code::blocks for a console application. I have the sqlite.exe which works fine from the console prompt. I have the amalgamation file as well which contains the source code. Hence, a **generalized step by step guide** could be useful to many as I've found many breaking their head over this, and even some get it to work, it was usually some quick fix solution (inferring from many SO questions on SQLITE and C).

Comment: What is the specific problem with compiling amalgamation file? Any errors?

Comment: @rkrahl Well, for one , this ( check comment on DieMartin's Answer) is what I get when I compile in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If your target is an embedded system you should use one of the toolchains for that specific target. We cannot recommend a compiler without knowing what your target is. 
It may have some kind of "gcc-ish" compiler or something completely different.

There are some useful tutorials for interfacing C with SQLite with examples. Take a look at this one for example (it assumes gcc compiler): [SQLite C/C++ Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_c_cpp.htm)

Comment: I have a TDM - GCC 64 bit , could that have anything to do with why I'm not able to compile sqlite? C:\sqsqsq>gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-min
gw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That error means that linker cannot find library called dl in your environment. libdl is library for dynamic linking, i'm not sure if it's necessary in windows. Firstly, try to remove -ldl from command line. If it won't work see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455160/using-libdl-so-in-mingw/13562093#13562093

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete solution that uses MinGW (which is GNU GCC for Windows).

http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/sqlite/embed_sqlite.html

But honestly? I don't believe you'll squeeze this rather big library in a `Cortex M0` MCU, which probably won't have enough flash memory to fit the library alone, not to mention dependencies, such as `libc`. This library requires dynamic memory management, which makes it rather unsuitable for bare-metal applications, unless you make yourself the trouble to implement all required operating system facilities (memory management, I/O subsystem, etc).

Unless you decide to switch to `Rasberry Pi` or `BeagleBone`-type of hardware, which runs `Linux`, you should find other solution.