# Trying to compile OpenVDB

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile `OpenVDB`, but I get a linker error telling me:

```
"cannot find -ldl"
```

That is the only linker I am getting. I have no idea what library `-ldl` belongs to. The makefile doesn't help either, so I'm guessing it is a standard lib. I am using Mingw-w64 on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using libdl.so in MinGW](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455160/using-libdl-so-in-mingw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-ldl` is a linker option to link to `libdl` library. This library is used to perform dynamic library loading (`.dll` in Window's world) through `dlopen`, `dlsym`... functions.

Since this library is not available on Windows, I think you could remove the `-ldl` from your `makefile`.

Since Window's equivatent functions are accessible by [kernel.lib](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599(v=vs.85).aspx), you do not need to add specific instruction in `makefile`.