# msys2 / mingw missing dynamic linker library

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32, msys, msys2

I am attempting to build [SpatiaLite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index) in [Msys2](https://www.msys2.org/). The build goes well until it attempts to compile the examples. It throws an error because the linker cannot find the [dynamic linker (dl) library](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libdl.html). Is this something that I should expect msys2/mingw to support? Am I missing a package?

I build spatialite using

```
./configure && make
```

Here is the compiler/linker output

```
Making all in examples
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/myuser/libspatialite-4.3.0a/examples'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -I./../src/headers  -g -O2 -MT demo1.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/demo1.Tpo -c -o demo1.o demo1.c
mv -f .deps/demo1.Tpo .deps/demo1.Po
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -I./../src/headers  -g -O2 -L../src -lspatialite -lm   -o demo1.exe demo1.o -L/mingw32/lib -lxml2 -lz -llzma -liconv -lws2_32 -lfreexl -liconv -lproj -lz -lsqlite3  -L/mingw32/lib -lgeos_c
libtool: link: gcc -I./../src/headers -g -O2 -o .libs/demo1.exe demo1.o  -L../src /home/myuser/libspatialite-4.3.0a/src/.libs/libspatialite.a -L/mingw32/lib -lpthread -ldl -lxml2 -llzma -lws2_32 -lfreexl -liconv -lproj -lz -lsqlite3 -lgeos_c
C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:372: demo1.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/libspatialite-4.3.0a/examples'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:473: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myuser/libspatialite-4.3.0a'
make: *** [Makefile:380: all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

msys2 needed the package `mingw-w64-dlfcn` which provides `libdl.a` and `libdl.dll.a`

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455160/using-libdl-so-in-mingw)

Comment: Full name is [mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-dlfcn)